# MYSQL: How to call multiple triggers on different tables after one insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have 2 tables

Employees:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | varchar(45) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| last_name | varchar(45) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| job_title_id | int | NO | MUL | NULL |  |
| teacher_id | int | YES | MUL | NULL |  |

Teachers:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| employee_id | int | NO | MUL | NULL |  |

I want to create a teacher and link the teacher to an employee, when i insert a row in employees table and that employee has job_title_id != 4.

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`employees` (`name`, `last_name`, `job_title_id`) VALUES ('sdf', 'sdf', '2');
```

I tried to make it with triggers, but I get error

> 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'employees' in stored function/trigger
> because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
> function/trigger.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `mydb`.`employees_AFTER_INSERT`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `employees_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON    `employees` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
BEGIN
IF new.job_title_id != 4 THEN
INSERT INTO teachers (employee_id) VALUES (new.id);
END IF;
END;
END$$
DELIMITER ;



DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `mydb`.`link_teacher_and_employee`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `mydb`.`link_teacher_and_employee` AFTER INSERT ON     `teachers` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE employees 
set teacher_id = new.id
where employees.id = (select employee_id from teachers where id = new.id);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I seem to understand why this is happening, but I don't know how to do it right.

Comment: Add the INSERT that produces the given error.

Comment: I don't understand the motivation for your `link_teacher_and_employee` trigger. It looks like a foreign key relationship. Why not make it the caller's responsibility (the inserter's responsibility) to add both rows within a single transaction? And enforce that with a FK constraint.

Comment: Note: Your triggers are circular.  Your teachers table could refer to the employees table.  Insert into the employees table first, then insert into the teachers table (with reference to the employee_id.

Comment: Remove the teacher_id from the employees table.  That's redundant.  Just join on employee_id.  No need for the teacher_id.  Now you can remove the second trigger.

Comment: agree with you Jon Armstrong. Thank you

Comment: @Akina, check the 'employees_AFTER_INSERT' trigger. It accepts a new employee id.

Comment: The task is not solvable in current scheme state. Insertion into teachers needs in `employees.id` generated for currently inserted row - this needs the row to be inserted already, i.e. this must be performed in AFTER trigger. But after this insertion you want to use generated `teachers.id` as a value for `employees.teacher_id` which must be performed in BEFORE trigger. But BEFORE trigger cannot be fired after AFTER trigger.

Comment: If you want to solve your task as you describe then you need in third table which will generate `teachers.id` - i.e. `id` will be autoincrement in this third table but not in `teachers` table.

Comment: But the root of the problem is in denormalized scheme. Now you must insert multiple rows in `employees` for the same employee if you need to have multiple different `job_title_id` for him. Which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Akina thanks for giving me advice. I followed Jon Armstrong's advice - I removed the "teacher_id" column from employees, and when I insert a row in "employees", I create a row in the "teachers" table using the "employees_AFTER_INSERT" trigger, and that's enough for me.